# How do firewalls interact with Comet protocols?

Tags: firewall

Generally speaking, how do firewalls handle [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) style protocols? Are there firewalls that are better at handling a large number of mostly idle long-polling connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most respond well, though some (particularly old/cheap models) have arbitrary time limits on connections. You're unlikely to have issues with a semi-modern firewall though.

Comment: Does this apply also to application-aware firewalls? (The kind that check for SQL injections and the like?)

Comment: Yes, unless the the data in the connection trips a rule.